# Problem with custom cursor with FF/chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cursor

I would like to use a custom cursor. That's work but sometime I got my custom cursor and the default cursor on Chrome/FF.

However I use the css property `cursor: none !important;`

Here's my function :

```
function init_cursor() {
    var cursor = $('.cursor');
    var circle = $('.cursor__circle');

    $(window).mousemove(function(e) {
        cursor.css({
            top: e.clientY - cursor.height() / 2,
            left: e.clientX - cursor.width() / 2
        });
    });

    $('.cursor-zone').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.cursor__wording').show();
        circle.css({
            transform: "scale(2)"
        });
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $('.cursor__wording').hide();
        circle.css({
            transform: "scale(1)"
        });
    });

    $(window).mousedown(function() {
        circle.css({
            transform: "scale(.2)"
        });
    }).mouseup(function() {
        circle.css({
            transform: "scale(1)"
        });
    });

    $('button, a').mouseenter(function() {
        circle.css({
            transform: "scale(1.3)",
            backgroundColor: "transparent"
        });
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        circle.css({
            transform: "scale(1)",
            backgroundColor: "#000"
        });
    });
}
```

My css :

```
html,
body,
* {
    cursor: none !important;
}

.cursor {
    position: fixed;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: none !important;
    z-index: 30000;
}

.cursor__wording {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    color: $white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1000;
}

.cursor__circle {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid $black;
    background-color: $black;
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

I tried to use an another solution with png of 1px, but I got the same problem :

```
cursor: url('../img/pictos/picto_cursor_black.png'), auto;
```

Here's my div to emulate my cursor :

```
<div class="cursor">
    <p class="cursor__wording">voir</p>
    <div class="cursor__circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Found a Typo in your JS: `$('button, a)')`, it should be: `$('button, a')`

Comment: Thank you. It's a wrong copy/paste of my function. It's not the same class on my project

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
function log(str) {
  $(".log").prepend("<p>" + str + "</p>");
}

function init_cursor() {
  var cursor = $('.cursor');
  var circle = $('.cursor__circle');

  log("Init started.");

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    log("Mouse move, " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY);
    cursor.css({
      top: (e.clientY - cursor.height() / 2) + "px",
      left: (e.clientX - cursor.width() / 2) + "px"
    });
  });

  $('.cursor-zone').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.cursor__wording').show();
    circle.css({
      transform: "scale(2)"
    });
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $('.cursor__wording').hide();
    circle.css({
      transform: "scale(1)"
    });
  });

  $(window).mousedown(function() {
    circle.css({
      transform: "scale(.2)"
    });
  }).mouseup(function() {
    circle.css({
      transform: "scale(1)"
    });
  });

  $('button, a').mouseenter(function() {
    circle.css({
      transform: "scale(1.3)",
      backgroundColor: "transparent"
    });
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    circle.css({
      transform: "scale(1)",
      backgroundColor: "#000"
    });
  });
}

$(function() {
  init_cursor();
});
```

```css
.cursor {
  position: fixed;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: none !important;
  z-index: 30000;
}

.cursor__wording {
  position: absolute;
  //display: none;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.cursor__circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.log {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.log p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor wording-see">
  <p class="cursor__wording">voir</p>
  <div class="cursor__circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="log"></div>
```

There are various syntax errors in JS and CSS. I modified them for the example. It does appear to work with these changes.

When passing to `.css()`, you want it to result in the exact styling that is needed. For `top` and `left`, if you pass a length, it must have a proper format:

> Sets the top edge position in `px`, `cm`, etc. Negative values are allowed.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp